# Robot framework Excel Library "Get Row Values"

Tags: robotframework

In Robot Framework, I'm trying to get values from excel sheet using excel library. I've observed below issue for the "Get Row values" keyword

```
Open Excel    E:/Robot/excel/Test.xls
@{Datas}=    Get Row Values    Sheet1    0    includeEmptyCells=False
Log to console    ${Datas}
```

If the datas in the column are from A1 to Z1, the values are updated in the ${Datas} properly, I'm using these values ${Datas} again to convert it into List and get the exact value from the sheet.

But now when it exceeds Z1, i.e A1,B1,...,Z1,AA1,AB1,AC1.. ${Datas} is not generated as same in the sheet. Its stored as something as below

```
    [('A1', u'Valli'), ('AA1', u'sdffgdg'), ('AB1', u'k'), ('AC1', u'h'),('AD1', u'jk'), ('AE1', u'j'), ('AF1', u";\\'"), ('AG1', u'jk'), ('AH1', u'j'), ('AI1', u'Kasthurikala')........]
```

I want the values as same as in the excel rather than alphabetical order [('A1','Value1'),('B1','value1'), ('Z1','ValueZ'),('AA1','ValueAA1')

Is there any solution?

Comment: Are you saying you want the values in the order of the sheet rather than in alphabetical order?

Comment: @Bryan: Yes, I want values in the order as same as in the sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort by the length of the second element and breaking ties with the first elemnt:

```
a = [('B1','value1'), ('Z1','ValueZ'),('AA1','ValueAA1'),('A1','Value1')]
a.sort(key=lambda x: (len(x[1]),x[0]))
print(a)
[('A1', 'Value1'), ('B1', 'value1'), ('Z1', 'ValueZ'), ('AA1', 'ValueAA1')]
```